# Urgent Call for Moderators

Tags: discussion, moderation

We recently had a few slots open for Moderator positions that we need to fill. Finding folks who are willing to take on these leadership positions [**is crucial to the continued existence of this site**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites).

We need your help filling **two moderator slots**. Please nominate folks you would like to see become provisional moderators for this site. Your input will provide valuable insight to help us make our selections. You can read more about the process here: **[Moderators Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).**

### The Nomination Process:

- **Nominate a user** by posting an 'answer' below. Each nomination should be a separate answer. Use the template at the bottom of this post to complete your nomination.
- **Self nominations are encouraged.** This is a volunteer activity, so users should not feel obligated to accept these positions. A self-nomination is simply a way to say, "I am very much interested in this, so let my record speak for itself."
- **Tell us about the candidates.** Nominations can include links to other activities like Area 51 participation, participation in other sites, or any relevant thoughts/links that may help us make an informed decision.
- **The nominee should indicate their acceptance** by editing the answer to say they accept/decline the nomination. Optionally, nominees are encouraged to write a bit about themselves following their acceptance.

  > I accept/decline this nomination.
  >
  > Hi, I am name/location/fun fact (all optional). I live in <location>, so I am generally active on this site from <time> to <time>. Some other things you may want to know about me are…

### Here is what we'll be looking for in a Moderator candidate:

We are looking for members who are deeply engaged in the community's development; members who:

- Have been consistently active during the earliest weeks of this site's creation
- Show an interest in their meta's community-building activities
- Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write
- Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [**A Theory of Moderation**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

---

### Nomination Template

To nominate a candidate, copy and paste the text below as an answer and complete your nomination writeup:

> <a href="http://alcohol.stackexchange.com/users/**UserID**">
>   <img src="http://alcohol.stackexchange.com/users/flair/**UserID**.png"></a>
>   <a href="http://meta.alcohol.stackexchange.com/users/**UserID**">
>   <img src="http://meta.alcohol.stackexchange.com/users/flair/**UserID**.png"></a>
>   ###Notes:
>   This nominee would be a good choice because …

[image]

Comment: Always willing to step up if it means a site not languishing in the land between moderators and death, but that's most definitely a last resort.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

I nominate [Monica Cellio](https://alcohol.meta.stackexchange.com/users/43/monica-cellio), if she's up for moderating one more site.

She would be a good choice because she is a long-time active user of this site, both as a direct contributor with answers and questions, but also in meta and community moderation activities.  She's also a thoroughly proven SE moderator, holding that position on several other sites in the network.

---

Monica here.  Thanks for the endorsement.  I'm willing to do it if needed; however, I'd prefer to see others step up, ones who aren't already moderators (or at least not moderators on as many sites).  I think this is a good opportunity for people to learn the moderation ropes in a friendly, supportive, low-stress environment, so rather than giving me my *fifth* diamond, I hope we'll see some new diamonded names.

I'm in the US eastern time zone (UTC-4 at the moment), and am generally around in my afternoons and evenings.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

Jamie is relatively new to the site (February 2016) but has been steadily active since then -- asking and answering (with good results), reviewing, flagging, and voting.  The profile declares: "Have a real passion and love for Beer".

I wouldn't normally nominate somebody with <500 rep and no meta posts, but this user brings activity and enthusiasm.  I think as part of a team including an experienced moderator, a user like this could step up and be effective in helping the community to grow.

---

Accepted (see comment).

Comment: I accept this nomination I may have not been on this site long but my love for all things alcohol is strong I visit this site almost every day (sometimes miss a weekend) and I love the community we have here and would love to part of helping it grow since the nomination i have posted in the meta to a good response so I feel I will be able to step up my game and really be an asset to the site. Thank you for your vote

Answer (score 3):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

This user has been active since the early days.  He(?) has a good track record of answers and is also active in reviewing.  As a homebrewer (and member on Homebrewing.SE) he can help us handle cross-site issues.  This would be this user's first diamond, and this seems like a site on which a new, interested moderator could learn the ropes.  (It's not like there aren't experienced moderators around, after all.)

Meta participation is light, but meta *activity* has been pretty light so if he's prepared to step up, I presume he would become more active on meta as part of that.

---

I decline the nomination, but with much appreciation for the thought; see below.

Comment: Thank you so much for the nomination!  Unfortunately, these days I'm wrapped up in work and other projects, and haven't been able to focus the appropriate attention to this SE.  When things calm down a little and I can focus more on my drinking & homebrewing, you'll see a lot more of me.  Thanks again!

Comment: @object88 thanks for responding, and I hope to see more of you here when things calm down for you.